# Android convert UTC Date to local timezone

Tags: java, android, date

I get this date string from my API : `"2015-12-07T14:11:15.596Z"`

But this date is in UTC format and I want to convert it in local time, how can I do it ?

I tried this :

```
try
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return simpleDateFormat.parse(this.created_at);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    Log.e("Error Date at Whisp", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

But it return me this error :

```
Unparseable date: "2015-12-07T13:21:17.996Z" (at offset 10)
```

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. These topics of parsing date-time strings, `ParseException`/”Unparseable“, and adjusting time zones, have been covered many hundreds of times already.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Date Format pattern is wrong. Change to:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
```

For more informations see the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I tried this but give me that "Unparseable date: "2015-12-07T13:21:17.996Z" (at offset 11)", he don't like the "T" I think

Comment: @JohnyBro Youhave the siglequotes arround the 'T'?

Comment: Yes, "yyyy-MM-dd'T' HH:mm:ss.S'Z'"

Comment: @JohnyBro Sorry my fault. remove the blank after the second single quote

Comment: Thx it work, I got this "Mon Dec 07 09:11:15 EST 2015" but how can I get something like "07.12 09:11" ?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `T` and the `Z` are not in your mask

Either

```
created_at = created_at.replace ("T", "").replace ("Z", "");
```

or modifiy your mask