# Convert UTC time to Local android

Tags: android, android-date

I am getting UTC time from server for eg - "2016-01-04T06:27:23.92". I want to convert it to Jan 4,2016 and time in Local formate. I am using following code but its not working -

```
Date localTime = new Date(commentDate);
String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.format(localTime));
Date fromGmt = new Date(gmtTime.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
commentDate = commentDate.substring(0, commentDate.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: Which is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting exception on "Date localTime = new Date(commentDate);" line. I have time in string formate eg - "2016-01-04T06:27:23.92"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049207/convert-utc-to-current-locale-time see ths link

Comment: Besides the aforementioned comment. It looks to me that your data string doesn't match your format string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android convert UTC Date to local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150865/android-convert-utc-date-to-local-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
     //commentDate = "2016-01-04T06:27:23.92"
     Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(commentDate);

     Date fromGmt = new Date(date1.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(date1.getTime()));
     Log.e("Date",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(fromGmt)); // print 2016/01/04 11:57:23 (0530 hour deviation)
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can change your date format according to your requirement.